# R function with functions as arguments, each with variable arguments

Tags: r, function, arguments, simulation, quantile

In answer to [a question on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/149522/7224), I wrote [a simple function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/149589/7224) that used arbitrary quantile functions as its arguments

```
etacor=function(rho=0,nsim=1e4,fx=qnorm,fy=qnorm){
  #generate a bivariate correlated normal sample
  x1=rnorm(nsim);x2=rnorm(nsim)
  if (length(rho)==1){
    y=pnorm(cbind(x1,rho*x1+sqrt((1-rho^2))*x2))
    return(cor(fx(y[,1]),fy(y[,2])))
    }
  coeur=rho
  rho2=sqrt(1-rho^2)
  for (t in 1:length(rho)){
     y=pnorm(cbind(x1,rho[t]*x1+rho2[t]*x2))
     coeur[t]=cor(fx(y[,1]),fy(y[,2]))}
  return(coeur)
  }
```

However, both `fx`  and `fy` may require their own parameters. For instance, when `fx=qchisq` or when `fy=qgamma`. As a default solution, in my implementation, I used

`fx=function(x) qchisq(x,df=3)`

and

`fy=function(x) qgamma(x,scale=.2)`

but this is quite time consuming.

For instance,

```
> rhos=seq(-1,1,.01)
> system.time(trancor<-etacor(rho=rhos,fx=qlnorm,fy=qexp))
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
      0.834       0.001       0.834
```

versus

```
> system.time(trancor<-etacor(rho=rhos,fx=qlnorm,fy=function(x) qchisq(x,df=3)))
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
      8.673       0.006       8.675
```

Comment: It's too time consuming to type "function"? I'm not sure what you're asking here exactly.

Comment: I don't write complicated functions myself, but I think you're looking for the `...` syntax: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#The-three-dots-argument

Comment: Are you asking how to pass variable arguments to a function? eg `df` or `scale`?

Comment: using the `...` syntax only works for one function: if `fx=qchisq` and `fy=qchisq`I want to be able to define two `df=3` and `df=5` for instance...

Comment: I don't think there's anything stopping you from (1) having `df.x` and `df.y` in your `...` for `etacor`, (2) parsing `...` to grab these and (3) passing the parsed-out values (if any are found) to `fx` and `fy`. It's complicated, but that shouldn't be too surprising.

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from having two more arguments, each a list with arguments for `fx` and `fy`, and then in the function you'd call them via `do.call` with a constructed list of arguments.

Comment: Regarding your edit....not sure why you're assuming that evaluating `qexp` is going to take the same amount of time as evaluating `qchisq`.

Comment: To further @joran's point. Look at `x<-runif(1000); microbenchmark::microbenchmark(qexp(x),(function(x){qexp(x)})(x), qchisq(x, 3), (function(x){qchisq(x, 3)})(x))`. It's not the `function()` part that's slowing things down, it's that you're using a more complicated distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An illustration of my comment above:

```
etacor1 <- function(rho = 0,
                    nsim = 1e4,
                    fx = qnorm,
                    fy = qnorm,
                    fx.args = formals(fx),
                    fy.args = formals(fy)){
    #generate a bivariate correlated normal sample
    x1 <- rnorm(nsim)
    x2 <- rnorm(nsim)

    fx.arg1 <- names(formals(fx))[1]
    fy.arg1 <- names(formals(fy))[1]

    if (length(rho) == 1){
        y <- pnorm(cbind(x1, rho * x1 + sqrt((1 - rho^2)) * x2))
        fx.args[[fx.arg1]] <- y[,1]
        fy.args[[fy.arg1]] <- y[,2]
        return(cor(do.call(fx,as.list(fx.args)),
                   do.call(fy,as.list(fy.args))))
    }

    coeur <- rho
    rho2 <- sqrt(1 - rho^2)

    for (t in 1:length(rho)){
        y <- pnorm(cbind(x1,rho[t]*x1+rho2[t]*x2))
        fx.args[[fx.arg1]] <- y[,1]
        fy.args[[fy.arg1]] <- y[,2]
        coeur[t] <- cor(do.call(fx,as.list(fx.args)),
                        do.call(fy,as.list(fy.args)))
    }

    return(coeur)
}
```

I am displeased with the apparent necessity of `as.list`. I feel like I should know why that is, but it is escaping me at the moment.

In using this function, it should not be necessary to pass in all arguments, but you do need to make sure any list you pass to `fx.args` or `fy.args` is named.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments and answer! I fear the core issue is that, as pointed out by [joran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324364/joran) and [Mr Flick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick), some quantile functions are much slower to execute than others:

```
> system.time(etacor(rhos,fx=function(x) qexp(x)))
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
      1.182       0.000       1.182 
> system.time(etacor(rhos,fx=qexp))
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
      1.238       0.000       1.239
```

versus

```
> system.time(etacor(rhos,fx=function(x) qchisq(x,df=3)))
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
      4.955       0.000       4.951 
> system.time(etacor(rhos,fx=function(x) qgamma(x,sha=.3)))
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
      4.316       0.000       4.314
```

So in the end using the definition of the function when it requires parameters does seem as a straightforward and easy solution. Thanks for all of your inputs.